# Find current data set using two SQL tables storing separately historical insertions and deletions

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Problem**

I need to do daily syncs of our latest internal data to an external audit database that does not offer an update interface. In order to update some records, I need to first generate and send in a deletion file to remove those records, and then follow by an insertion file with the same but updated records in it.

An important detail is that all of the records in deletion files must match the external records verbatim, in order to be deleted.

**Proposed approach**

Currently I use two separate SQL tables to version control what I have inserted/deleted.

Let's say that right now the `inserted_records` table looks like this:

```
    id | file_version | contract_id | customer_name | start_year
    9  | 6            | 1           | Alice         | 2015
    10 | 6            | 2           | Bob           | 2015
    11 | 6            | 3           | Charlie       | 2015
```

Accompanied by a separate and empty `deleted_records` table with identical columns.

Now, if I want to

- change the `customer_name` from Alice to Dave on line id 9
- change the `start_year` for Bob from 2015 to 2020 on line id 10

Two new lines in `inserted_records` would be generated, line 12 and 13, in turn creating a new insertion file 7.

```
    id | file_version | contract_id | customer_name | start_year
    9  | 6            | 1           | Alice         | 2015
    10 | 6            | 2           | Bob           | 2015
    11 | 6            | 3           | Charlie       | 2015
    12 | 7            | 1           | Dave          | 2015
    13 | 7            | 2           | Bob           | 2020
```

Then their original column values in line 9 and 10 are then copied onto the previously empty `deleted_records`, in turn creating a new deletion file 1.

```
    id | file_version | contract_id | customer_name | start_year
    1  | 1            | 1           | Alice         | 2015
    2  | 1            | 2           | Bob           | 2015
```

Now, if I were to send in the deletion file 1 first followed by the insertion file 7, I would get the result that I wanted.

**Question**

**How can I query the current set of records, considering all insertions and deletions that have occurred? Assuming all records in `deleted_records` always have matches in `inserted_records` and if multiple, we always delete records with smaller file version numbers first.**

I have tried by first writing one to query the `inserted_records` for the latest records grouped by `contract_id`.

```
select top 1 with ties *
from insertion_record
order by row_number() over (partition by contract_id order by file_version desc)
```

This would give me line 11, 12 and 13, which is what I wanted in this particular example. But if we also wanted to delete the record line 11 with Charlie, then my query wouldn't work anymore as it doesn't take `deleted_records` into account, and I have no idea how to do it in SQL.

Furthermore, my nut tells me that this approach isn't solid as there are two separate and moving parts, perhaps there is a better approach to solve this?

Comment: How do you want to match these rows? Can you match them by the `id` column? There has to be some correlation, otherwise it's impossible

Answer (score 0):

> How can I query the current set of records

I don't understand your question.  Every SQL query is against the current set of records, if by that you mean the data currently in the database.

I do see a couple of problems.

1. Unless the table you're deleting from has a key defined, even an exact match on every column risks deleting more than one row.
2. You're performing an *ad hoc* update with UPDATE's transaction guarantee.  I suppose the table you're updating is otherwise idle, and as a practical matter you don't have to worry about someone else (or you) re-inserting the deleted rows before your inserts arrive.  But it's problem waiting to happen.

If what you're trying to do is produce the set of rows that will be the result of a series of inserts and deletions, you haven't provided enough information to say how that could be done, or even if it's possible.  There would have to be some way to uniquely identify rows, so that deletions and insertions can be associated.  (They don't match on all columns, after all.) And you'd need some indication of *order of operation*, because it matters whether INSERT follows or precedes DELETE.